# Confused about advanced Koa functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I have a project using Koa generators and I'm frustrated with writing "controllers". I have looked for examples, but actually there aren't many results on Github based on the keywords so I suspect I'm doing something quite wrong.

My app uses `koa-router` to route endpoints to generators.

Then the controller looks like this

```
export function* postEvent () {
  const self = this

  const user = yield User.findOne({slug: this.params.slug}).exec()

  if (user) {
    user.events.push({
      [ ... ]
    })
    yield user.save( (error, event) => {
      yield postBlacklist({
        [ ... ]
      })
      .then( event => {
        self.status = 200
        self.body = "Event created for: " + user.slug
      })
    })
  } else {
    [ ... ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, this generator doesn't work. I use `yield` to get the app to wait for `user.save()` to finish. But I can't do `yield postBlacklist()` because I've "used up" my `yield` command. If I remove the second `yield`, I will get a 404.

So how would I nest one promise-returning thing within another like this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot yield from within a callback. But why won't this work?

```
export function* postEvent () {
  const user = yield User.findOne({slug: this.params.slug}).exec()

  if (user) {
    user.events.push({
      [ ... ]
    })

    // should return a promise in latest versions of mongoose.
    // Otherwise, write your own wrapper which does so.
    var event = yield user.save();  

    yield postBlacklist({
        [ ... ]
    })
    .then( event => {
      this.status = 200
      this.body = "Event created for: " + user.slug
    });
  } else {
    [ ... ]
  }
}
```